# Industry standard HDMI extension?

Tags: hdmi

We're recently purchased a new lighting console in our small theatre that supports video output over HDMI. We want to run the signal from the control room out to the proscenium but don't want to settle for a consumer grade HDMI extender. What is a quality device that we can permanently install that can transmit a strong HDMI signal? What are most theatre spaces using for this application?

Comment: Used a $20 adapter I had laying around and discovered that the console itself has a built in extender. It's sending the signal 160ft no problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you’re going wired, you’re going to be limited to roughly 25 feet before you need to reclock the signal. HDMI simply isnt designed for long runs. There are 50’ cables out there, my experience is their performance is spotty.

You could go with a Wireless Solution HDMI solution. I recommend the Nyrius line of transmitters/receivers which you can buy on Amazon. The Pro version is roughly $300 and you can get a solid HD signal to reach 100+ feet line of sight.

Otherwise, buy the Black Magic Design converters, one to convert HDMI to HD-SDI and one to convert HD-SDI to HDMI and run a long BNC cable. That solution will give you 300 Feet.

If you need longer, do same as HD-SDI concept but do Fiber LCLC instead. you can run it 25 Miles.

Comment: I’d argue not to use wireless, having worked in theater and event AV as a student. Wireless is not super reliable, and in theater even the most reliable stuff is unreliable. I’d go with an HDMI extender, running the signal either over HD-SDI, Cat6 or Fiber. It’s worth shopping around for these products, but SE is not really a product recommendation site.